# Ошибка вывода запроса в php

Tags: php, mysql

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in Z:\home\mysait.by\www\index.php on line 14

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hm,$un,$pw,$db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->connect_error);
$query = "SELECT * FROM order_2";
$result =$conn->query($query);
if (!$result)die($conn->error);
$rows=$result->num_rows;


for ($j=0;$j<$rows;++$j)
{
   $result->data_seek($j);
   echo 'id: '.$result->fetch_assoc()['id_order'].'<br>';
   $result->data_seek($j);
   echo 'model: '.$result->fetch_assoc()['model'].'<br>';
   $result->data_seek($j);
   echo 'name: '.$result->fetch_assoc()['name'].'<br>';
  // $row =$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  // echo 'id: ' .$row['id_order'].'<br>';
  // echo 'model: ' .$row['model'].'<br>';
   //echo 'name: ' .$row['name'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: версия php у вас какая? такой синтаксис `$result->fetch_assoc()['id_order']` с версии 5.4 или 5.6 _(точно не помню)_ допускается.

Comment: Автор, чем вас не устраивает цикл `while()`, который дается в примерах к методу `fetch_assoc()` http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples И не надо на каждое значение по два метода вызывать!

Comment: Может быть ! Версия 5.3 в денвере!

Comment: А что возвращает  метод data_seek($j)?

Comment: @Visman по три! :)

Comment: @teran, тогда уж на каждую строку по 6 :)

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, у вас стоит версия php < 5.4. Конструкция вида `$array[$key]()` называется разыменованием массива (англ. array Dereferencing) и была введена в php 5.4.

- [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing)
- [Переход с PHP 5.3.x на PHP 5.4.x](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php)

Очень советую обновиться как минимум до PHP 7.1, т.к. даже версии 5.6 и 7.0 поддерживаются **только** на уровне security update'ов. Предыдущие версии давным давно канули в лету и совершенно неактуальны даже для обучения. См. [Supported Versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)